# question about relationship in coredata iphone

Tags: iphone, core-data, entity-relationship

Im working with core data in the iphone,
it seems that is going fine (creates db and save some data), until I found some thing I dont get yet

- I have 3 entitys (Employee, Days, Centre) and one of them have relationships of one to many to the other 2,

  ```
  ENTITY       RELATIONSHIP      ENTITY
  Employee>>>>days(one to many)>>Days (inverse of Days, employee)
  Employee>>>>centre(one 2 many)>Centre (inverse of Centre, employee)
  ```

in my sqlite generated db, I check it with sqlite manager (firefox), and the relationship is showing for one entity (ZCENTRE)after (Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZEMPLOYEE) , but not showing for in that order (is that the expected order?? for my other entity (Z_DAYS), it shows after an attribute, so it makes me think is being taken as an attribute not an entity in the code??

in the code for the model, for centre.h I have

```
 #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
 @class Employee;
 @interface Centre :  NSManagedObject  
 {}
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * centres;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) Employee * employee;
 @end
```

and the model centre.m

```
       #import "Centre.h"
       #import "Employee.h"
       @implementation Centre 
       @dynamic centres;
       @dynamic employee;
       @end
```

this was the one working, and the code for the Days.h and Days.m is preatty much the same, with the change for the attributes of course,

- but is not showing on the sqlite in the expected order??
  also, in the employee table on the sqlite, do the relationships appear?? in wich order?? (I dont have them showing on the sqlite manager!)

do I have to call them in the model? (I think so!)

```
for the Employee.h>>>@class Centre;
@class Days;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Centre * centre;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Days * days;
```

and for the employee.m

```
   #import "Employee.h"
   #import "Centre.h"
   #import "Days.h"
   @implementation Employee
   @dynamic centre;
   @dynamic days;
```

- so the questions again: I need the relationships to show in the db and check in the sqlitemanager they are infact working,

ok, thanks a lot!

Comment: ok, just checked an example and the relationship can appear in sqlite after an attribute, as long as is numbered in order (1,2,3,4...) but the question about the main entity remains, how to set the relationship of employees with days and centre, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to think about:

- Have you got all the relationships defined in your Managed Object Model?
- Do you need custom subclasses of `NSManagedObject`? There's no need to create them as separate classes if you don't need custom behaviour. If you do need that, then are the entities to use those classes set in the aforementioned model?
- Why do you care about the sqlite database at all? It's really just an implementation detail, and the schema generated shouldn't concern you. Do you have problems traversing these relationships in your code?

Comment: hi, tnx - in my managed object model, I just call the database of type momd, - I dont need custom subclasses cheers, - I care about the schema because I have imported large number of entries from a csv and noticed this things, thanks again!